# Sorting arrays of variable length arrays of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a set of sizes and a target size.  Using some knapsack algorithm I get all the possible answers.  So, all the answers have the same sum, but contain differing number of elements.  I first sort by count so that I get the maximum number of elements.  Now, I'm left with a subset that all have the same sum and the same count.

Here is a sample (there are actually many, many, more answers):

```
[24, 33, 21, 22],
[24, 26, 27, 23],
[24, 27, 28, 21],
[34, 23, 21, 22],
[26, 23, 29, 22],
[24, 40, 36],
[34, 26, 40],
[30, 38, 32],
[24, 37, 39],
[40, 38, 22],
```

Now, I want to bring the ones that have the biggest elements to the top (¡without breaking the internal order!):

```
[24, 26, 27, 23],  <-- 23 is the biggest smallest
[26, 23, 29, 22],  <-- 22 is the second biggest smallest
[24, 27, 28, 21],  <-- 21, 24 is the biggest second smallest
[24, 33, 21, 22],  <-- 21, 22, 24 is the biggest third smallest
[34, 23, 21, 22],  <-- 21, 22, 23 is the second biggest third smallest
[30, 38, 32],  <-- 30 is the biggest smallest
[34, 26, 40],  <-- 26 is the second biggest smallest
[24, 37, 39],  <-- 24, 37 is the biggest second smallest
[24, 40, 36],  <-- 24, 36 is the second biggest second smallest
[40, 38, 22],  <-- 22 is the fourth biggest smallest
```

If that makes sense to you, then please tell me the name of the sorting algorithm that can handle it.  Everything I've found so far expects to use only one fixed element of the internal array for sorting, but I want to use as many as is necessary to get it sorted.

Obviously, I can do this by brute force, but I'm hoping there's an elegant solution that already exists.  I just don't know the right keywords to search for.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest making a copy of the arrays so they are in sorted order internally. Then you can more easily compare them for sorting. Finally, put the original arrays in order according to where their sorted versions ended up. Do you have an implementation language in mind? Some languages have better libraries or language support for this kind of thing than others.

Comment: I don't know if there's a name for it, but `sorted(seq,key=lambda x: (len(x), sorted(x)))[::-1]` would reproduce your results in python -- you'd sort by a key function which combined the length of each element with the sorted order of each element, as TH suggested.   Any language which supports (1) sorting using a key function and (2) sorting of sequences should be able to do it easily.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I can do it by brute force.  But there could be hundreds of elements resulting in tens of thousands of results.  I was hoping to avoid having to maintain a sorted copy of each internal array thus instantly doubling the memory usage.  Or sorting on every round, thus drastically slowing the overall progress.  I'm pretty good at pounding my way through code, but not so good at creating elegant algorithms to avoid that kind of pounding. :-\  I just look at it and think, "there's a smart way to do this--wish I was smart." :-P

Comment: I suspect you're optimizing way too early: "tens of thousands" is quite small, many sorting techniques perform very well on already sorted data, if memory really is such a problem (and I doubt it is) that you can't even keep 2 copies of your data in memory you don't need to store the result of the key function, etc.  And in fact I also suspect that you've already spent more time thinking about it than you'll possibly save, but without the actual scale of your problem I can't prove it, so maybe you'll have to come to that conclusion on your own.  ;-)